# While plotting scatter graph using plotly the plot is separated by categories even when the data is ordered

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-dash

So I am trying to plot a scatter graph like this using plotly [Code and plot without specifying color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O697i.png)

The plot is correct as long as I don't specify the color attribute to color the point according to categories. But when I specify the color the graph turns into this and the categories are separated into 3 little plots  [Code and plot for after specifying color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBm8n.png). Is there any way I can specify the color and preserve the order of the plot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- it's always better to ask a SO question with your sample code as marked up text, not embedded in image and sample data
- have implied the structure of your data frame and simulated it with random data
- core concept, when column used for **color** is a categorical (string), **plotly** will create a trace per value in the categorical series.  Given your **xaxis** is a categorical as well (not continuous) this will result in traces be partitioned
- given you only want one trace,  have updated **marker_color** of single trace to `map()` a categorical value to a color

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# simulate data frame
df20 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "SectionContentDetailType": np.random.choice(["Lesson", "Quiz"], 100),
        "Page_Title": [
            chr(ord("A") + i // 26) + chr(ord("A") + i % 26) for i in range(100)
        ],
        "Number of Users": np.sort(np.random.randint(100, 2500, 100))[::-1],
    }
)

# create figure in same way
fig = px.scatter(
    df20, x="Page_Title", y="Number of Users", hover_data=["SectionContentDetailType"]
)

# add marker color to single trace figure
fig.update_traces(
    marker_color=df20["SectionContentDetailType"].map(
        {
            t: c
            for t, c in zip(
                df20["SectionContentDetailType"].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
            )
        }
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, works perfectly now and yes will use markup now on

Comment: One more question, how do you show legend in the above figure?